# Symmetric random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk

The following question is somewhat related to:

[Asymmetric random walk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394601/asymmetric-random-walk)

Let $(X_i)_{i=1}^n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $\Pr(X_i=1)=\Pr(X_i=-1)=1/2$. Let $S_0=0$ and, for $1\le i\le n$, $S_i = X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_i$. Let $\Pi_n$ denote the number of strictly positive terms among $S_1,\ldots,S_n$. In the symmetric case, namely, when $p=1/2$, the law of $\Pi_n$  is known to be (e.g. Feller, Ch. XII.8)
$$
\Pr(\Pi_{n}=k) = {2k\choose k}{2n-2k\choose n-k}\frac1{2^{2n}}.
$$
I am trying to find asymptotic (in $k,m,n$) formula for the number of positive terms given the value of the last term, or more generally,
$$
\Pr(\Pi_{n}=k,S_n=m)
$$
Of course not all values of $k,m$ are possible. Also, clearly, the additional event that $S_n=m$ breaks the nice symmetry of the process $(X_i)_{i=1}^n$, so in some sense $(X_i)_{i=1}^n$ can be thought as being drawn uniformly over some subspace of the hyper-cube. Note that this probability can be probably upper bounded by removing the $S_n=m$ constraint but assuming that $(X_i)_{i=1}^n$ is now an asymmetric process with success probability that is proportional to $m/n$.

Comment: Assuming that $m \ge 0$ and that $m$ and $n$ have the same parity,  then I think at the extremes $\Pr(\Pi_{n}=n \mid S_n=m) = \dfrac{m}{n}$ while $\Pr(\Pi_{n}=m \mid S_n=m) = \dfrac{ 2 \binom{n-m}{(n-m)/2}}{\left({n-m}+2\right)\binom{n}{m}}$

Comment: Agree, thanks! However, I need the general case :\

Comment: @Henry Actually, can you prove that?

Comment: I think the first is the [ballot theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem) while the second is essentially the "lattice paths staying below the diagonal" interpretation of [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) for the first $n-m$ steps.